A movie about a girl and a boy singing in high school
I forgot name of one Hollywood's singing-based movies. Help me find its name...
In that movie, one boy and one girl meet in a New Year party. They're offered to sing a song; both are new to singing but still they sing it very nicely. After that they meet in high school and they attend an arts competition.
Boy's father is a basketball teacher in his high school, so he prefers that his son become a basketball player and took part in a competition. In another plot, one rich bother-sister pair well known for dancing try to create problem for the main couple. The girl's clever friends support her for singing and meeting that boy.
At last, all (his father, girl's friends, basketball players etc.) come to support that boy and girl's singing, and they won it.

It's High School Musical from 2006.

Troy Bolton and Gabriella Montez are two totally different teenagers who meet at a party while singing karaoke on New Year's Eve. One week later Troy goes back to his high school, East High, in New Mexico to find that Gabriella is a new student there. They quickly become close friends and accidentally audition for the school musical. After getting a callback, drama queen Sharpay Evans and her sidekick brother Ryan are furious. Then Chad, Troy's best friend and basketball teammate, and Taylor, Gabriella's new friend on the decathlon team, must find out a way to make Gabriella hate Troy.

It spawned 2 direct sequels. Here's the trailer:


 
